# there is any way to open and read a file over a SSH connection?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ssh

I have an access to some server where there is a lot of data. I can't copy the whole of data on my computer.

I can't compile on the server the program I want because the server doesn't have all libs I need.

I don't think that the server admin would be very happy to see me coming and asking to him to install some libs just for me...

So, I try to figure if there is a way to open a file like with,

```
FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode);
```

or

```
void std::ifstream::open(const char* filename,  ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in);
```

but over a SSH connection. Then reading the file like I do for usual program.

both computer and server are running linux

Comment: Not without using a dedicated SSH library providing the abstraction.

Comment: You could install the libs you need locally in your `$HOME` directory so you don't need to bother the admin.

Comment: ssh X forwarding maybe?

Comment: Is the "lot of data" a "lot of files" with reasonable size, or a few files with huge (terabyte) size?

Comment: You should have explained in your question what kind of application are you coding and what kind (and organization) of the remote huge data

Comment: Please **edit the question** to give more context, what kind of data, what kind of app, what approximate file size, number of files, total data volume...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch several terabytes. It's about my internship at the university, I have to process data of a simulation

Comment: Please **edit your question** don't comment it. And several Terabytes does not mean much. See my answer!

Comment: @Galik my first I dea was to use `ldd MyProgram` and to copy the libs... but there is a big problem, my computer is 32bits, the server is 64bits... And even so, there is so much libs, that would be very messy... it tooks me several hours before I thought to compile all libs on the server.

Comment: @bob-theunholymetalmachine: next time you ask a question, please explain it better and motivate it much more.

Comment: @bob-theunholymetalmachine I've rolled this back to the version I think everyone answered. Once there's an answer you can't really change the question and the question turned into an unreadable stream-of-consciousness mess after all the revisions.

Comment: @RobertLongson I got a lesson..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are working on your Linux laptop and the remote machine is some supercomputer.

First non-technical advice: ask permission first to access the data remotely. In some workplaces you are not allowed to do that, even if it technically possible.

You could sort-of use [libssh](https://www.libssh.org/) for that purpose, but you'll need some coding and read its documentation.

You could consider using some [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) file system (on your laptop), e.g. some `sshfs`; you would then be able to access some supercomputer files as `/sshfilesystem/foo.bar`). It is probably the slowest solution, and probably not a very reliable one. I don't really recommend it.

You could ask permission to use [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) mounts.

Maybe you might consider some [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) access (if the remote computer has it for your files) using some HTTP/HTTPS client library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (or the other way round, some HTTP/HTTPS server library like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/))

And you might (but ask permission first!) use some [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) connection (e.g. start manually a server like program on the remote supercomputer) perhaps thru [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) or [libgnutls](http://www.gnutls.org)

At last, you should consider installing (i.e. asking politely the installation on the remote supercomputer) or using some [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) software (e.g. a [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) or [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) or [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) server) on the remote computer and make your program become a database client application ...

BTW, things might be different if you access a few dozen of terabyte sized files in a random access (each run reading a few kilobytes inside them), or a million files, of which a given run access only a dozen of them with sequential reads, each file of a reasonable size (a few megabytes). In other words, DNA data, video films, HTML documents, source code, ... are all different cases!

Comment: I have the permission to access the data remotely. I'm going to check FUSE right now!

Comment: Probably inefficient (slow) and unreliable (perhaps buggy & faulty).

Comment: your insistence to asking me to edit my question. Helped me to realize I was going in a wrong direction. *Merci*

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `fopen` on a path, you can use `popen` on an ssh command. (Don't forget that `FILE *` streams obtained from `popen` are closed with `pclose` and not `fclose`).

You can simplify the interface by writing a function which wraps `popen`. The function accepts just the remote file name, and then generates the `ssh` command to fetch that file, properly escaping everything, like spaces in the file name, shell meta-characters and whatnot.

```
FILE *stream = popen("ssh user@host cat /path/to/remote/file", "r");

if (stream != 0) {
   /* ... */
  pclose(stream);
}
```

`popen` has some drawbacks because it processes a shell command. Because the argument to `ssh` is also a shell command that is processed on the remote end, it raises issues of double escaping: passing a command through as a shell command.

To do something more robust, you can create a pipe using `pipe`, then `fork` and `exec*` the `ssh` process, installing the write end of the pipe as its stdout, and use `fdopen` to create a `FILE *` stream on the reading end of the pipe in the parent process.  This way, there is accurate control over the arguments which are handed to the process: at least locally, you're not running a shell command.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer to your question is *no*, as already stated several times (unless you think about implementing *ssh* yourself which is out of scope of sanity).

But as you also describe your *real* problem, it's probably just asking the wrong question, so -- looking for alternatives:

#### Alternative 1

Link the library you want to use *statically* to your binary. Say you want to link *libfoo* statically:

- Make sure you have `libfoo.a` (the object archive of your library) in your library search path. Often, development packages for a library provided by your distribution already contain it, if not, compile the library yourself with options to enable the creation of the static library
- Assuming the GNU toolchain, build your program with the following flags: `-Wl,-Bstatic -lfoo -Wl,-Bdynamic` (instead of just `-lfoo`)

#### Alternative 2

Create your binary as usual (linked against the dynamic library) and put that library (`libfoo.so`) e.g. in `~/lib` on the server. Then run your binary there with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib ./a.out`.

Comment: I'm not sure that answers the question. But it is a useful advice (which might not work in general).

Comment: So "no" isn't the answer here? ;) *scnr* -- well in fact I just assumed from the way the OP described the problem that he *would* have a solution using a library in mind

Comment: Weel, a FUSE based `sshfs` filesystem on the local laptop is a *yes* answer, even if I agree it is probably not a good answer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch you're right, it is an answer, I understood the scenario the wrong way around. Still, running a program on the server would solve the problem as well -- at least i guess?

Comment: @FelixPalmen actualy I was thinking to send the lib on the server... but a  `ldd MyProgram` to get the whole `.so` made me sick... using lib statically is something that I never did so far... I may be wrong, but I think I would have to compil a lot of things to get my program working...

Comment: Actually, doing exactly what you suggest requires to have both, the computer and the server, having the same architecture (what is not the case here)... But you too, got the feeling I was going in the wrong direction

Comment: Well, the answer would just get a bit more complicated for different architectures... still possible, see cross toolchains ... but a lot more work, having to compile all the dependencies, so if there are a lot, not practical any more

Answer (score 1):

You can copy parts of file to your computer over SSH connection:

- copy part of source file using `dd` command to temporary file
- copy temporary file to your local box using `scp` or `rsync`

You can create a shell script to automate this if you need to do that multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly(1) open a file over ssh with fopen() or ifstream::open. But you can leverage the existing `ssh` binary. Simply have your program read from stdin, and pipe the file to it via ssh:

```
ssh that_server cat /path/to/largefile | ./yourprogram
```

(1) Well, if you mount the remote system using [sshfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) you can access the files over ssh as if they were local.